# angularjs form-button not validated or enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs form that pulls default data from scope. With the default data the form is expected to be validated and hence enable the button for submission but the reverse is the case except data is entered on the input field and this enables the button. here is the snippet

```
<div ng-controller="FormValidationController as frmValidationController" class="ui basic segment">

  <form class="ui form" name="frmValidation" novalidate>    
      <div ng-class = "{'has-error':frmValidation.option1.$invalid && !frmValidation.option1.$pristine}"
           class="required field">
          <label>Selection</label>
          <input ng-model="option" ng-minlength="3" formcontrol
                 name="option1" placeholder="Option" type="text"
                 class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" required>
           <div _ngcontent-c5="" ngxerrors="option1">
               <div class="input-error-message" ngxerror="validName" hidden="">
                    selection should be there
                </div>               
          </div>
          <p ng-show = "frmValidation.option1.$invalid && !frmValidation.option1.$pristine"
             class = "input-error-message">required</p>
      </div>
```

if the model has data, the button should be enabled on launch but this never happens and I want it to happen

```
<button ng-click="submit(); frmValidationController.submitForm(frmValidation.$valid)"
    ng-disabled ="!frmValidation.$dirty || frmValidation.$invalid"
    class="ui primary button" tabindex="0" type="submit">
  Proceed
</button>
```

Comment: **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears.

Comment: no insights on what could be the problem

Comment: Setting `class="ng-dirty"` won't set the `$dirty` state to `true`. The `ngModelController` ignores class settings.

Comment: Setting `class="ng-valid"` won't set the `$valid` state to `true`. The `ngModelController` ignores class settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
ng-disabled ="!frmValidation.$dirty || frmValidation.$invalid"
```

Specifically:

```
!frmValidation.$dirty
```

The form is only dirty if an actually user has interacted with it. Because you're loading default data, the form is filled in correctly but the user has NOT touched or "dirtied" it.

Remove that check and it should work as expected I believe.

Comment: so I should use just this >> !frmValidation.$dirty in the form

Comment: It looks like you don't need to use  `!frmValidation.$dirty` at all. You should only be binding `frmValidation.$invalid` to ng=disabled.